# Multi part password salt - Common practice

Tags: encryption, cryptography, passwords

When storing a hashed password the salt is usually persisted with it. This usually isn't a security issue as it is my understanding that a salt is merely designed to prevent rainbow lookup tables, and with a unique salt per password each password needs to be cracked individually via brute force.

Why is it not common practice to have a second static part to the 'salt' that shared across all passwords that is never persisted to the database. This would ensure that compromising the database alone would not be enough to crack the password via brute force, as the hacker would also need to know about this secondary static part to the password salt?

Comment: This question would be better suited to either [security.se] or [crypto.se].

Comment: What you're asking about is called a "Pepper" - give it a Google.  It's a bit of an ongoing debate actually...

Comment: They have already have one [Password Hashing: add salt + pepper or is salt enough?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough)

Comment: Nobody stops you to use a key/pepper, I would certainly engourage you to do so. Why it is not common practise is probably because it requires a deeper understanding of the matter and because the security gain is much smaller than what you gain with salting and key-stretching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a salt is merely designed .. individually via brute force. 
>   Why is it not common practice to have a second static part to the 'salt' that shared across all

I'd say - because the 'simple' salt fulfils its purpose. A simple salt is enough forcing an adversary to crack each password separately.

In theory - using any authentication framework doesn't prevent you adding another salt parameter (and I see that used, though not very often). So indeed you can do that, however another "system" salt would have another purpose.

In my opinion - adding another "system" salt would help in case only the database is compromised (e.g. backups are leaked, ..). Usually compromising the database comes with compromising whole system, including the secrets or additional configuration